# How to detect the next semver version automatically, based on the commit history? (CLI alternative to commit-analyzer)

Tags: git, release, release-management, semantic-versioning, semantic-release

We have a custom script with some tricky steps which accepts the version number as an argument, something like this:

```
./custom-release-script.js 1.2.3
```

I would like to automate the releasing process and run that script from CI. In order to do that, I need a tool which will analyze commit history and based on commit messages output the next semver version:

```
$ yarn what-is-the-next-release-version
1.2.3
```

There's [semantic-release/commit-analyzer](https://github.com/semantic-release/commit-analyzer) but it works only as a plugin for `semantic-release`, and I need the standalone solution.

Comment: This is the wrong place to ask this kind of question. Find a popular forum on whatever CI platform you are integrating on and ask them.

Answer (score 2):

I recommend using **standard-version** (https://github.com/conventional-changelog/standard-version), a module that replaces **npm version** command.

If you follow their structured commit messages convention, it will automagically detect the next version of your project.

It's super easy to use and it will:

- Bump the version on your package.json
- Update Changelog.md with the new commits
- Create a tag with the new version

I hope it helps.

Comment: Amazing, didn't know about that module and works like a charm! Thanks!

Comment: The standard-version library has been deprecated by the author, with a recommendation to use [release-please](https://github.com/googleapis/release-please) instead.  For folks who still want to use standard-version, a fork has been started at [commit-and-tag-version](https://github.com/absolute-version/commit-and-tag-version).